# Validating Blazor WebAssembly EditForm with server-side checks

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

For Blazor WebAssembly, I see many examples and articles that talk about data annotation validation, but no examples on how to use API's to validate a form.

I want to be able to do the following on submit:

- Check field value if it already exists on the server.
- If yes, then raise an error for that field, with the message ("This field value already exists.").
- Otherwise, call service to create or update value and redirect to a success page.

What is the ModelState counterpart for Blazor WebAssembly forms?

Comment: Consider using FluentValidation instead : https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/04/blazor-fluentvalidation/

Answer (score 0):

Blazor doesn't currently support async validations.

What you'll need to do is to call the server yourself and display your own mark-up representing errors.